# Amazon EC2 Ubuntu 12.04 - unable to route all traffic through OpenVPN

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, iptables, openvpn

I'm trying to use OpenVPN on my remote Ubuntu 12.04 web server, but as soon as OpenVPN is running, I can't connect to the internet.

Befor starting OpenVPN, route says:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         ip-172-31-16-1. 0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
172.31.16.0     *               255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

and after:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.200.4.1      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         172.31.16.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.200.4.0      *               255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.200.4.1      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
172.31.16.0     *               255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
184.170.137.2   172.31.16.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
```

184.170.137.2 is the VPN. The OpenVPN HOWTO suggests to use

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.200.4.0/22 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

which throws

```
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-172-31-26-178
```

(172.31.26.178 is the internal IP).

If I do the following, I can use the VPN for a single website:

```
route add -net {website ip} netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 10.200.4.1 dev tun0
route del -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 128.0.0.0 dev tun0
route del -net 128.0.0.0 netmask 128.0.0.0 dev tun0
```

How can I change this to work for the whole web? Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be a question for http://askubuntu.com/ or maybe http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've tried on serverfault and askubuntu, nothing yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what the problem was. Connection to hidemyass is done by hma-vpn.sh script, you have to change

```
#!/bin/sh
cat <<EOEO >> /tmp/hma-ipcheck.txt
 *******************************************
* *
* You are now connected to HMA Pro! VPN *
* *
 *******************************************

Checking new IP address...
EOEO
nohup /tmp/hma-ipcheck.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 >
rm /tmp/hma-routeup.sh
EOF
```

to

```
#!/bin/sh
cat <<EOEO >> /tmp/hma-ipcheck.txt
 *******************************************
* *
* You are now connected to HMA Pro! VPN *
* *
 *******************************************

Checking new IP address...
EOEO
vpn_gw=\$(ip route | grep tun0 | grep 0.0.0.0 | cut -d" " -f3)
route del -net 0.0.0.0 gw {your-original-default-gateway}
route del -net 0.0.0.0 gw \$vpn_gw
route del -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 128.0.0.0 gw \$vpn_gw
route del -net 128.0.0.0 netmask 128.0.0.0 gw \$vpn_gw
route add default gw \$vpn_gw
echo "nameserver 208.67.222.222">/etc/resolv.conf
nohup /tmp/hma-ipcheck.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 >
rm /tmp/hma-routeup.sh
EOF`enter code here`
```

This will change your default gateway to be the vpn server.
You can skip `echo "nameserver 208.67.222.222">/etc/resolv.conf` if your dns are accessible through the vpn

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thanks for your help. I'm not the admin of the VPN. I tried `route del 10.200.4.1`, but that throws `SIOCDELRT: No such process`.

Comment: you should try wit more specific rule, like route del -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 128.0.0.0 10.200.4.1 dev tun0

Comment: actually what do you want, to route all traffic through vpn or just to use it to access vpn's network(10.200.4.0/24)

Comment: `route del -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 128.0.0.0 gw 10.200.4.1 dev tun0` doesn't work either. Neither does `route del -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 128.0.0.0 dev tun0`, which is interesting, as it worked in my example above where I first add an IP to the routing table.

Comment: I'd like to route all traffic through vpn.

Comment: are you sure that the vpn server actually route traffic, or it's just vpn? When you delete vpn added routes and add new one (site specific), like you did above, do you check with `traceroute  {website ip}` does the traffic goes through vpn?

Comment: traceroute returns ´traceroute to {website ip} ({website ip}), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * * ...´

Comment: If I kill OpenVPN, it returns ´traceroute to {website ip} ({website ip}), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  ec2-50-112-0-162.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (50.112.0.162)  0.827 ms  0.521 ms  0.753 ms
 2  205.251.232.164 (205.251.232.164)  0.948 ms  0.633 ms  0.901 ms
 3  205.251.232.158 (205.251.232.158)  0.926 ms 205.251.232.152 (205.251.232.152)  1.021 ms 205.251.232.158 (205.251.232.158)  1.061 ms
 ...´

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39249/discussion-between-vladimir-dimitrov-and-simon)